# PyQt: align text left and right in a QListView

Tags: python, pyqt, alignment, qtreeview, qlistview

I have a list-view which shows lists of strings representing key, value pairs. The strings all have the same character length, but due to the different pixel length, they show a different length in the list. So, it looks something like this:

```
someValue         1000.93
someOtherValue     98.7
oneMoreValue     11200000.00
```

Is there a way to nicely format the strings so that it looks aligned left and right, like this:

```
someValue          1000.93
someOtherValue        98.7
oneMoreValue   11200000.00
```

I create the strings like this:

```
s = '{:20}'.format(key) + '{:>20}'.format(val)
```

Comment: Using spaces to align text in columns is almost impossible to do consistently when proportional fonts are used. There is also the issue of re-formatting the list whenever items are added/removed, or when the listview is resized. If one part changes, the formatting for the whole list needs to be re-calculated (because it depends on knowing the length of the longest item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html) can be configured to work like a `QListView`, which will then allow for multiple columns. Each column can then have its own aligment settings (amongst other things). It will also preserve the alignment after resizing.

A basic implementation would be something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ListView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))
        self.model().setColumnCount(2)
        self.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.setAllColumnsShowFocus(True)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(
            0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(
            1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

    def addItem(self, key, value):
        first = QtGui.QStandardItem(key)
        second = QtGui.QStandardItem(value)
        second.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.model().appendRow([first, second])

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = ListView(self)
        for text in 'Aquamarine Red Green Purple Blue Yellow '.split():
            self.view.addItem(text, str(16 ** len(text)))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```